# Retrieve flight data from delta.com using vba

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I am trying to get flight data from delta.com using vba. The city is *Bozeman (**BZN**)* and I just need the `BZN -> MSP` route. I tried stepping through the code and it jumps everywhere. Sometimes, it does display all the data.

The part where there is an error is the date 2015-08-23. Really any day where there is a Delta Connection flight. I have deduced that it has to be because the info box on the website that displays the Delta Connection label has a class name of `schedulesTableCell`, just like every other box in the table.

For that day, the output should be:

```
1203    6:00AM  MSP
4518    9:00AM  MSP
2287    11:05AM MSP
2318    1:25PM  MSP
```

But, many times it appears as a variation, some of which are:

1)

```
1203    6:00AM  MSP
4518    9:00AM  MSP
```

2)

```
1203    6:00AM  MSP
4518    9:00AM  MSP
2287        MSP
```

3)

```
1203    6:00AM  MSP
4518    9:00AM  MSP
2287    11:05AM MSP
```

Note that, I have tried counting to see if there was a pattern, but couldn't find one right away. Granted, I assume any pattern would show within 20 attempts.

And I have to use vba, as this will be used to help reduce my workload.

```
Sub populateFlights()
    'declare variables
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    'run internet explorer
    IE.navigate "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate=" _
    & Range("Date").Text & "&arrivalAirportCode=msp"
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    'set variable values
    Dim findFlt As Integer
    Dim flt As String, dep As String, cty As String, city As String
    Dim r
    Set Doc = IE.document
    findFlt = -1
    offTime = -7
    city = Range("B3").Text

    'fill in flight info
    For r = 0 To 4
        On Error Resume Next
        findFlt = findFlt + 1
        offTime = offTime + 9

        'retrieve data from delta.com
        flt = Doc.getElementsByName("flightNumber")(findFlt).Value
        dep = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(offTime).innerText)
        cty = Doc.getElementsByName("legArrivalAirportCode")(findFlt).Value

        IE.Quit

        'skip duplicate flights from data loop
        If flt = Range("F35").End(xlUp).Text Then
            GoTo Skip
        End If
        Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(1, 0).Value = flt

        'forward one box if city was retrieved instead of scheduled departure time. This is where I try to adjust for delta connection box
        If dep = city Then
            offTime = offTime + 1
            dep = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(offTime).innerText)
            'trim date from response
            Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(0, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(dep, 1, InStr(dep, "M")))

        'continue code
        Else
        'trim date from response
        Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(0, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(dep, 1, InStr(dep, "M")))
        End If

        Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(0, 2).Value = cty
Skip:
    Next r
    findFlt = -1

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more context? Where is it failing? When it doesn't display what you want, what part of it doesn't get displayed? etc.

Comment: I just added more, thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array indexes (offTime and findFlt) you were providing were not always correct, causing the issue. However, because the tables provided by Delta are 9 columns wide (excepting the * rows), the below should work.

```
Sub populateFlights()
'declare variables
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim i As Integer
'run internet explorer
IE.navigate "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate=" _
& Range("DATE").Text & "&arrivalAirportCode=msp"
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set Doc = IE.document

For i = 0 To 1000
On Error GoTo second
   a = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(i)
Next

second:
Offset = 0
    For r = 0 To (i / 9) - 1

        flt = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + Offset).innerText
        dep = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + 2 + Offset).innerText)
        cty = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + 3 + Offset).innerText

        Cells(1 + r, 6) = Right(Replace(flt, " *", ""), 4)
        Cells(1 + r, 7) = Trim(Left(dep, 7))
        Cells(1 + r, 8) = cty
    If InStr(flt, Chr(42)) > 0 Then
        Offset = Offset + 1
    End If
    Next r
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, just one thing - WOW. Mind blown.